# Using a NoSQL system to store session data

Tags: session, web, nosql, redis, scalability

I'm trying to design a stateless and scalable web system. For the 'session' concept, I'm considering using Redis as the warehouse of sessions.

But do you think using a NoSQL system is suitable for that purpose?  Is it an overkill? Should I consider another NoSQL system *(I'm not looking for a shopping list of course. I mean another NoSQL that is more suitable to store session data than Redis)*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But do you think using a NoSQL system is suitable for that purpose?

Yes, NoSQL systems are suitable for this use case, namely K/V stores like redis if your session data are not too complex.

> Is it an overkill?

No, it's a right tool for the right job. Redis is used in many scenarios and session store is one where it excells thanks to it's speed and support for advanced data structures which might come handy for you.

> Should I consider another NoSQL?

There are other NoSQL solutions which might be used as a session store, for example [riak](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.3.1/cookbooks/use-cases/session-storage/) or [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/couchbase-usecases.html), but which one you choose depends on how complex your data are and also other factors like scalability and durability requirements.